# Why output is not 311?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a='3';
        int b=011;
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

**Output is 60**

can someone explain why java behaves like this ?

Comment: If you can tell us why you think it should be 311. What is your reasoning for that? 011 is octal for 9 (decimal)

Comment: Convert to strings first.

Comment: Both `char` and `int` are numeric types. Numeric literals with a leading zero are interpreted as octals, so `011` is in fact a `9`. The `char` ``3`` has a decimal value of 51 in the ascii system. And then your code prints `51`+`9`.

Answer (score 0):

Literals with a leading zero are **octal** literals. Any number prefixed with a 0 is considered **octal**. **Octal** numbers can only use digits 0-7, just like decimal can use 0-9, and **binary** can use 0-1. To define integer literals as octal value in Java is effortless.